# ViewModel and Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

I am learning jetpack compose.
I would like to integrate compose and `ViewModel`.
But I am unable to find the `ViewModel` class. I can't extend `ViewModel`.

**app.gradle**

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha06'
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-alpha07"
```

Comment: Always add `android-jetpack-compose` tag for questions related to Jetpack Compose.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: To my understanding the error is: Cannot resolve ViewModel...

Comment: can not resolve ViewModel .....class or interface expected

Answer (score 1):

For ViewModel, you can add these dependencies:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0"
// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// ViewModel utilities for Compose
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version"
```

For related dependencies and their latest version, check out the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle).

Comment: it didnt work .